# How to switch timezone in renderer process?

Tags: proxy, timezone, electron

My Electron application uses a set of proxies in different renderers. I'm trying to set an apropriate Timezone for each proxy session independently of the main process.

I can change Timezone for the whole application at startup by doing this:

```js
const process = require('process');
process.env.TZ = 'America/New_York';
```

But how can I achive Timezone switching for individual renderer or `webview`?